# Retrieve IoT Hub Twin from ServiceBus triggered azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-iot-hub

We're sending data from IoT devices to Azure IoT Hub and trying to pass a certain type of message to an Azure Function.

For now, we did it by creating an Azure Service Bus endpoint and creating a *Message routing* in IoTHub. It works as expected, with the message being received correctly by the Azure Function.

Now, we'd like to get the *DeviceId* from IoT Hub in the Azure function, as well as *Tags* defined in the *Device Twin*, and I'm completely lost in how to do it.

If we were to use an `EventHubTrigger`, it seems that it would be straightforward, doing something like this:

```
public static class Test
{
    [FunctionName("TestQueueTrigger")]
    public static void Run(
        [EventHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "IoTHubConnection")]
        EventData message,
        Twin deviceTwin,
        TraceWriter log)
    { ... }
}
```

But it's really not clear how this could be done with the Service Bus trigger.

Also, we would like to store all messages (independently from the route) to Azure Data Lake storage, and I'm a bit lost on how that would work.

Comment: Would you like to trigger function on the Device Twin Change Events via ServiceBus? All Azure IoT Hub telemetry messages can be stored to ADL storage independently (no routes, no custom endpoint) from the azure stream analytics job.

Comment: in the case of passing some additional values from the device (for instance, type of message), you can use a message properties collection (that's for user), the other properties collection such as a system properties is holding info such as deviceId, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure IoT Hub device-to-cloud message format is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct). There is no device twin properties in this format. The device twins are stored in the cloud backend, their changes can be notified based on the iot hub routes to the specific endpoint (built-in and/or custom endpoint).

Your example of the function "*TestQueueTrigger*" is using an [azure-functions-iothub-extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-iothub-extension.) for version 1. The extension input binding **Twin** allows to get the device twin using a separate call within the extension:

```
deviceTwin = await registryManager.GetTwinAsync(attribute.DeviceId);
```

Basically, this extension can be used also for *ServiceBusTrigger* binding. 
Note, that this extension can be used only for function version 1, so I do recommend to get the device twin within the function using for example a [REST API Get Twin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/gettwin) call.

**Update**

The following code snippet shows an example of the *ServiceBusTrigger* function and the REST API Get Twin call.

run.csx file:

```
#r "..\\bin\\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.dll"
#r "..\\bin\\Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared.dll"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"


using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared;

// reusable proxy
static HttpClientHelper iothub = new HttpClientHelper(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureIoTHubShariedAccessPolicy"));

public static async Task Run(Message queueItem, ILogger log)
{
    // payload
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(queueItem.Body)}");

    // device identity Id
    var deviceId = queueItem.UserProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"];

    // get the device twin
    var response = await iothub.Client.GetAsync($"/twins/{deviceId}?api-version=2018-06-30");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    Twin twin = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Twin>();

    log.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(twin.Tags, Formatting.Indented));

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}


// helpers
class HttpClientHelper
{
    HttpClient client;
    DateTime expiringSaS;
    (string hostname, string keyname, string key) config;

    public HttpClientHelper(string connectionString)
    {
        config = GetPartsFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://{config.hostname}")};
        SetAuthorizationHeader();         
    }

    public HttpClient Client
    {
        get
        {          
            if (expiringSaS < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1))
            {
               SetAuthorizationHeader();  
            }         
            return client;
        }
    }

    internal void SetAuthorizationHeader()
    {
        lock (client)
        {
            if (expiringSaS < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1)) 
            {
                string sasToken = GetSASToken(config.hostname, config.key, config.keyname, 1);
                if (client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization"))
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", sasToken);
                expiringSaS = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
            }
        }
    }

    internal (string hostname, string keyname, string key) GetPartsFromConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        var parts = connectionString.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2)).ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1].Trim());
        return (parts["HostName"] ?? "", parts["SharedAccessKeyName"] ?? "", parts["SharedAccessKey"] ?? "");
    }

    internal string GetSASToken(string resourceUri, string key, string keyName = null, uint hours = 24)
    {
        var expiry = GetExpiry(hours);
        string stringToSign = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(key));

        var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
        var sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, $"SharedAccessSignature sr={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri)}&sig={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature)}&se={expiry}");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyName))
            sasToken += $"&skn={keyName}";
        return sasToken;
    }

    internal string GetExpiry(uint hours = 24)
    {
        TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        return Convert.ToString((int)sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds + 3600 * hours);
    }
}
```

function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "queueItem",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "myQueue",
      "connection": "myConnectionString_SERVICEBUS"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I find the documentation for the Azure Functions and IoT Hub is still pretty so-so and it's really confusing to understand what should be used between v1, v2 and all the different ways to create an Azure Function.

Comment: if I would like to use the REST API call, is there something simple to get the needed authentication token in the function?

Comment: The point is, the device twin is not a part of the iot telemetry message, so we have to query cloud backend via the Azure IoT Hub service-facing endpoint. The DeviceId is a part of the message stored in the message system properties collection. In other word, the iot message can be triggered by AF, but the query must be a separate call either in the input binding extension or within the function body.

Comment: the REST API GetTwin call is a good choice, based on the DeviceId you can obtained a device twin properties, the authorization header can be implemented based on the following document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security

Comment: Note, that once we have a sas authorization header, there are many useful calls via REST API to the service-facing endpoint, for example: CreateDevice, DeleteDevice, UpdateDeviceTwin, SendDirectMethod, etc., almost everything except to send a message to the device (that's a AMQP message)

Comment: Another option that I used to get the Twin is to use the NuGet package *Microsoft.Azure.Devices*. It simplifies the call the the REST APIs.